# Wordpress custom multipage form on custom page templates 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have created a wordpress website now i want to use multi page form on wordpress i created 3 page templates and used that on 3 pages http://example.com/step1/ , http://example.com/step2/  all having different page templates. and each template having a form.

step1 page:

form action="http://example.com/step2/" method="post"

step2 page:

form action="http://example.com/step3/" method="post"

when i click on submit button on each page it will redirect me to 404 page who having  same url as i mentioned in the form. but not that page exactly. page doesnot contain any form. on.

**Please tell me how to trasfer data from page to page.**

Comment: Can you please change the permalink structure with **Post Name** in settings -> Permalink.

Or you can change the form action like **"http://example.com/?p=page_id"**

Comment: no i cant change...this structure is the part of the website... please tell me how to use action in the form to reach that page

Comment: I have edited previous comment, please see that.

Comment: i tried but nothing worked

Comment: when you view the page from wp-admin edit page section is there the page showing correctly?